# What are some tricks to solve Progressions quickly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Recently while solving few questions related to Progressions(specifically, A.P.), I realized one thing that in question like, "*Find the sum of following series*" and suppose the terms are up to $n^{th}$ places.

Then instead of going by the formula(s), I can simply add the first $3$ to $4$ given elements of the series and that would give me a rough idea of where the summation would belong. And since we are given Multiple Choice Question), I can solve it much more quickly.

So, is there any other trick that you may be aware of or formulated on your own related to solving any type of Progression? If yes, then please share it with us.

Comment: What do you mean by MCQ? Furthermore, if with A.P. you mean arithmetic progressions, then summing up a few of the first terms will only give you a reasonable approximation if you are lucky and will definitely not be useful in more general settings.

Comment: You can create a recursion and try to solve with generating functions, by example, you can see the _howto_ in books as _Concrete math_ of Graham and Knuth, or in [_Generatingfunctionology_](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) of Wilf. There are a lot of "tricks" about this.

Comment: While arithmetic and geometric series ("progressions" understood as finite sums) have convenient closed forms, this is not something that can be generalized without qualification.  Your adjuration to "add the first 3-4 given elements of the series" would seem helpful only for series that are rapidly converging, as the $n$th places might take us far away from that starting segment.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough I thought that everyone would be aware that what MCQ means. Is it because that this term is not popular in your country? Anyway, I've updated the question you may check there. And that would also answer the rest of your question ;-)

Comment: @Anoneemus I'm from USA, and I don't believe I have ever heard the abbreviation MCQ used...  At the very least, the idea of a "multiple choice question" is far enough removed from mathematics (and more soundly in the realm of pedagogy), that it is reasonable to expand the acronym.

Comment: @hardmath But don't you think that if we are in an exam, and we're provided with choices, then the most **efficient** way to solve these questions would be applying any trick instead of going the long way (assuming that you/I/everyone using these tricks also know the proper way).

Comment: @apnorton That's weird. I'm from India and almost everyone in the country and almost every exam in the country (even STEM related) are generally in the MCQ format.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm actually not a *maths-fan-boy* and looking at the index of that book, made me go faint :P

Comment: Believe me @Anoneemus: it is not hard to understand and learn, at least the topic that I described before. Ofc you will need some time to go deep on this but its not hard at all, after all there is no analysis here or topology or calculus or geometry... just some algebraics manipulations (and not too abstract).

Comment: @Masacroso If you're saying that much, then I'll surely give it a read. Anyway, looking forward for someone to share *their* known tricks related to Progressions.

Answer (score 3):

"Tricks" are always useful!

Anyway, here are some points for consideration.

**P1. Positions in an AP or GP are relative**

> *Example*:
>   Given $T_2=p, T_4=q$ find $T_{10}$, where $T_n$ is the $n$-th term in the AP.

Think of $T_4-T_2=q-p$ as one "step".
$T_{10}$ is 3 steps away from $T_4$ (think $T_2, T_4, T_6, T_8, T_{10}$).
Hence $T_{10}=q+3(q-p)=4q-3p$.
In this way we avoid having to first work out $a$ and $d$ by solving simultaneous equations for $T_2, T_4$ and then applying the formula for $T_{10}$, which would be more laborious.

Similar, if the progression was a GP instead of an AP, then 
$$T_{10}=q\cdot \left(\frac qp\right)^3=\frac {q^4}{p^3}$$

**P2. Visualize AP as a straight line graph**

It might be helpful to visualize an AP as a straight line graph, with number of terms on the $x$-axis and value of each term on the $y$-axis.

The sum of the number of terms may be approximated by the area under the graph.

**P3. A zero or negative term index may be a useful concept to provide symmetry**

Taking into account P1 it may sometimes be useful to apply the concept of a zero or negative number-of-term index in order to provide symmetry to simplify the solution of a problem.

> *Example*:
>   Three consecutive terms in an AP have a sum of 21 and product of 280. Find the three terms.

Let the three terms be $a-d, a, a+d$.
(NB: Here we consider $T_0, T_1, T_2$, instead of the usual $T_1, T_2, T_3$, WLOG).

Sum: 
$$(a-d)+a+(a+d)=3a=21\Rightarrow a=7$$
Product:
$$(a-d)a(a+d)=a(a^2-d^2)=280\\
7(49-d^2)=280\\
d=3$$
Hence the three terms are $4, 7, 10$.

This is much faster than solving for the terms $a, a+d, a+2d$ .